# Neocomplcache causing Vim slow down

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I noticed a slow down in my VIM movement and i have pinned down the culprit to neocomplcache. 
`let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1`.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Does it get slow immediately when you open a file or after some editing? Try neocomplete, it's faster.

Comment: Its happened after first editing. Also I have tried neocomplate, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Maybe it conflicts with some plugin. Have you tried to disable temporary all others? Also try `let g:neocomplcache_disable_auto_complete = 1` to invoke the completion with TAB key only.